# How to dynamically adjust the height of SVG to adjust to overflow

Tags: html, svg

All:

Currently I have a SVG inside a div.

Just consider this as a table, I have several rows, each one has a text and a color label, I will add more rows when I drag in some text.

I wonder how can I detect if DIV is overflow?

Comment: If the bounds of the svg are greater than the div I guess.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, the problem for me is how to determine the bound

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)